# spark submit with --jar and arguments of Main class

Tags: apache-spark

How can I submit spark jar to cluster with argument:

```
./spark-submit --class package.Main --master spark://master_IP:7077 --deploy-mode=cluster --jars /spark/examples/jars/local.jar s3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv
```

`s3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv` is the argument for the main function.

I got the error:

```
Jar url 's3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv' is not in a valid format.
Must be a jar file path in URL format (e.g. hdfs://host:port/XX.jar, file:///XX.jar)
```

How can I pass the argument in this case?

It just works without `--jar` on the master machine, but I need to upload the local jar, so `--jars` is a must

Comment: --jars are additional jars (apart from the application jar file) you want to upload, usually containing dependancies.  If you have only one jar file (and no other dependancies) you should not use `--jars`. The application jar (along with any other jar file specified with `--jars`) will be uploaded.

Comment: hi @shanmuga, no, I tried, it does not work, the master node cannot see the local jar.

Comment: If you main method is in --jar you could give any empty file as application jar. `spark-submit --jars /spark/examples/jars/local.jar <path_to_empty_file> 's3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv'`

Answer (score 0):

As you have applied --jars /spark/examples/jars/local.jar s3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv

It is expecting the 2nd file also to be a jar, I have reorganized your command, please try the below one:

```
./spark-submit --class package.Main /spark/examples/jars/local.jar --master 
spark://master_IP:7077 --deploy-mode=cluster s3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv
```

Note: you need not specify --jars for your main jar, it is an option provided for additional jars.

Secondly I believe you must have handled "s3://a_bucket_here/tests/BlackFriday.csv" as args(0) in your code

Comment: it does not work, without --jars, then the cluster does not see my local jar, I said before, --jars is must

Comment: Vo, if your refer to this link - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html
No where it uses "--jars" option to submit application.
Command used in the specified link to perform spark submit:
"./bin/spark-submit \ --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \ --master local[8] \ /path/to/examples.jar"


Secondly "--jars" options is for providing additional jars required by the program, again this statement is supported by this link:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-submit.html